# How can i update ngx-bootstrap in my angular project

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap

I am using angular version of @angular/cli": "~8.3.25 and ngx-bootstrap": "^5.3.2", and now I want to update my ngx-bootstrap version to ngx-bootstrap": "^8.0.0" so what is the way to update the ngx-bootstrap version to latest version in existing angular project with out affecting all the functionality .

Answer (score 4):

One can install specific version of a package by

```
npm i package_name@version
```

In your case it will be

```
npm i ngx-bootstrap@8.0.0 --save
```

--save flag register package to your package.json dependencies.

Comment: Check the package version compatibility with your Angular version before installing / updating package.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
ng update ngx-bootstrap
```

but I'm not sure that nothing will break, probably it will be necessary to manually update the components if there are breaking changes